# how do I plot two seaborn plots using subplots?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot two series side by side in seaborn style but this doesn't work:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, nrows = 1, figsize = (15,5))
ax1 = sns.distplot(data_1['Mileage'])
ax2 = sns.distplot(data_2['Mileage'])
```

It seems to be plotting both ax1 and ax2 in the ax2 subplot. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the individual subplots `ax1` and `ax2` to the `ax` argument while plotting. The [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) states that too.

```
sns.distplot(data_1['Mileage'], ax=ax1) # <--- ax1 passed here
sns.distplot(data_2['Mileage'], ax=ax2) # <--- ax2 passed here
```